# Why does passing a method as an argument (&block) not work?

Tags: ruby, proc

`clock` takes a block:

```
def clock(&block)
  hours = Time.new.hour
  puts hours
  hours.times do
    block.call
  end
end
```

This works, and puts `"DONG"` on the screen, based on the hours of today:

```
clock do
  puts "DONG..."
end
```

I'm trying to pass `dong` method:

```
def dong
  puts "DONG..."
end
```

to `clock` as its block. This:

```
clock(dong)
```

throws an error:

```
`clock': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Can someone explain why the first one works, but the second doesn't? Do you have to explicitly define the code block you're passing, or can you reference another method as a code block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

```
clock(dong)
```

Doesn't call `clock` with the `dong` method as a block, it calls it with the result of calling the `dong` method. Thus, you get argument error, because you try to call a method (`clock`) with one argument, while it expected none (except for an optional block, which does not count).

To use the `dong` method as a block in the invocation, you can do:

```
clock(&method(:dong))
```

`method(:dong)` will give you a `Method` object representing the `dong` method (instead of calling it), while `&` will convert it to proc (and then to block).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Result of dong = puts-ing "DONG", and that is an argument to clock. Clock should have zero arguments, just an optional block of code. (simply restating your answer for my own edification). Thanks, @ndn! I like @sagarpandya82 syntax below.

Comment: from_irb> [5, 7, 8, 1].each(&method(:puts))
5
7
8
1

Answer (score 1):

To pass a *block* you have to write the block-code within curly braces (or `do` and `end`)

```
clock() { dong }
```

or more simply

```
clock { dong }
```